# PyTelegramBotApi NameError: name 'message' is not defined

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == "test":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "hello")
```

NameError: name 'message' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == "test":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "hello")
```

callback не знает что такое message, к этому атрибуту надо обратиться через call.message.chat.id